# How to share image to Whatsapp with support for above and below Android 10

Tags: kotlin

most examples found were base on below android 10. and  MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage() is deprecated in android 10. below is my code that using bitmap as stream, this will throw error, Would appreciate if you can help how to share image to whatsapp for above in kotlin. Thanks

```
   btnSocialMedia.setOnClickListener {

          val stream = ImageHandling.GetProperImageRotation.BitmapToByteArray(bitmapCreated!!)
          val intent = Intent()
          intent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
            
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,stream)
          
            intent.type = "image/*"
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Share photo"))


        }
```

Comment: You mentio  `MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage()` where is thar used in your code? Also, what does the crash says?

Comment: This method is deprecated when I used minSdkversion:26 and TargetSdkversion :29  The above code, intent.putExtra(intent.EXTRA_STREAM , uri) need uri instead of stream.  So, I m stuck as I cannot use MediaStore InsertImage()  since i used Target Sdk 29